# Google Places API in Android gives Place StatusCode as PLACES_API_USAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED

Tags: google-places-api

I have used Google Places API for adding the place. Below is the code for GoogleApiClient and Adding a Place.

Start indented code:

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
            .Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, 0, this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

AddPlaceRequest place =
            new AddPlaceRequest(
                    "xyz",
                    new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude),
                    "2095",
                    Collections.singletonList(Place.TYPE_SHOE_STORE),
                    "+123456789",
                    Uri.parse("www.abc.com/")
            );

        Places.GeoDataApi.addPlace(mGoogleApiClient, place).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {

                if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " + places.getStatus().toString());
                    places.release();
                    return;
                }

                final Place place = places.get(0);
                Log.i(TAG, "Place add result: " + place.getName());
                places.release();

            }


        });
```

I am getting Output as :

> Place query did not complete. Error:
>   Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_USAGE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, resolution=null}

I have not even requested more than 25 times for Google Places API. Even if I try from different account also it gives me the same error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using an API key?